# Copied SSH - cant RUN - where to edit

Tags: ssh

I copied SSH to run 2nd instance of SSH just like this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1497376

but when I start service, I get

```
service started [OK]
```

After that I use `service status` and service responds with `sshd2 service stopped`.

I ran `/usr/sbin/sshd2 -p 22 -D -d -e` and I got the following error message:

```
bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed - Address already in use
```

I don't know where and what to edit to get it running on port I want it to run on (I need ssh1 to run on 22 and ssh2 to run on 2200)..

My question is: how to fix this in order for the sshd2 service to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THIS IS THE GUIDE FOR RED HAT (LIKE) SERVERS**

> 1) Create copy of sshd config and name it as your new sshd instance

```
# cp -p /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/new_sshd_config
```

> 2) Create copy of sshd init.d file and name it as your new sshd
>   instance

```
# cp -p /etc/rc.d/init.d/sshd /etc/rc.d/init.d/new_sshd
```

> 3) Bind pam.d files

```
# cd /etc/pam.d/
# ln -s sshd new_sshd
```

> 4) Edit your new config

```
# mcedit /etc/ssh/new_sshd_config
a) At the bottom of the file add:
    a1) Port (portnumberyouwant)
    a2) PidFile=/var/run/new_sshd.pid
    a3) AllowUsers "users you want to allow"
```

> 5) Edit your old config

```
# mcedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
a) At the bottom of the file add:
    a1) Port (standardportnumber)
    a2) DenyUsers "users you want to deny"
```

> 6) Edit your new init.d file

```
# mcedit /etc/rc.d/init.d/new_sshd
a) Edit following:
    a1) prog="new_sshd"
    a2) SSHD=/usr/sbin/new_sshd
    a3) PID_FILE=/var/run/new_sshd.pid
b) Add following:
    b1) OPTIONS=' -f /etc/ssh/new_sshd_config '
```

> 7) Try your new daemon

```
# service new_sshd start
```

> 8) Check if working

```
# service new_sshd status
```

> 9) If OK, run following commands:

```
# chkconfig --add new_sshd
# chkconfig --list | grep new_sshd
    Expected output:
    new_sshd       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

> Now you have your 2nd ssh daemon set up. At this moment, you can edit
>   ip tables (If needed.)